# Deterministic random noise generator from multiple 64-bit inputs?

Tags: c#, random, noise

I am trying to create a pseudo-random number generator in C# that produces the same output, given the same set of inputs. It needs to be fast, accept 64 bit numbers and, particularly important allow an arbitrary set of inputs. The output should be a double between [0 and 1}.

The inputs, for the most part will be a seed value that stays constant during the lifetime of the app, and one or more other numeric values, such as an x, y, z and w coordinate, which may themselves be of type int32, int64 or double.

I've tried adapting some other random number generators I found, but I keep getting massive problems with clumping, mainly due to the fact that I have no idea about the theory surrounding the topic, or the mathematical properties of prime numbers, which seem to play a role in most cases.

I want to use this function for generating the random noise that will be used internally within a number of other algorithms, including my own, and standard algorithms such as Perlin noise, amongst others.

How should I go about this?

Comment: "particularly important allow an arbitrary set of inputs." - You can Hash any value and use that hash as the seed.

Comment: I've just been coming to the same conclusion, i.e. constructing a byte array of my inputs and generating the hash of that.

Comment: If you'll generate hash from byte array you may want to take care about negative zero and floating point accuracy.

Comment: It looks like 4D or 5D Perlin or Simplex noise will do the job. But what is the purpose of x, y, z and w? Do you expect the noise to be a continuous function along these four dimensions? It sounds like you don’t really know how to describe the properties of the noise you’re looking for, so maybe you should give more details about what exactly you’re going to need it for.

Comment: I basically want a multi-seeded random number generator that does not change its output with successive iterations. Perlin Noise, Simplex Noise, etc are very purpose-specific. I'm looking for white noise. TV static in a sense. I have a few different places to apply it; I want the base generator as a tool in my belt, so to speak. I have a solution now, which I'll post when the code is complete.

Comment: I don't understand how this is any different than any other PRNG? The seed is the value at which a PRNG begins processing; the characteristics of the bit size (32 vs. 64) will simply determine the number of bits that the PRNG has with which to shift in registers without over/underflow. Output between 0 and 1 is about binding the results to a range. I mean, using multiple inputs is ok, it's just about what you're doing with them once they're there (bitwise ops to give a unique 3rd value?), but your output is always a predictable value because of the seed. Maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @stslavik actually a PRNG is exactly what I wanted, but after a lot of failing at Google searching, I couldn't find any that took an arbitrary number of inputs, so I figured I had to make my own. The other difference is of course that it needed to be unchanging - i.e. I found many generators, but they were all designed to change their output on successive runs. I wanted it to generate the same output every time, given the same set of inputs. I'm not saying my solution below is perfect, but sometimes you just have to run with something until someone points you in a better direction.

Comment: @NathanRidley Generally if they seed to Time (common practice to get "unique" results on successive runs), you'll have that problem. The nice part is that you usually end up with a true seeded PRNG (reliable output given an input). There are cases where the code (apparently inadvertently) will access garbage addresses, and this is why what might appear to be a PRNG gives you unpredictable results (just a "gotcha" to keep an eye out for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a pretty slow rng, but approximately 10 times faster than the Murmur3 based. Reseeding for every generated number has a cost, so does requiring a large number of seeds that all have a non-systematic influence on the outcome.

**Update:** There really isn't any reason to allow weak bits, this version should have no obvious patterns.

```
class Prng
{
    const double shift3 = .125;
    const double shift9 = shift3 * shift3 * shift3;
    const double shift27 = shift9 * shift9 * shift9;
    const double shift53 = shift27 * shift27 * 2.0;
    public ulong rndlong(ulong a, ulong b, ulong c, ulong d){
        ulong e = ((a ^ (b >> 14 | b << 50)) + ((c >> 31 | c << 33) ^ (d >> 18 | d << 46)))*1911413418482053185;
        ulong f = (((a >> 30 | a << 34) ^ c) + ((b >> 32 | b << 32) ^ (d >> 50 | d << 14)))*1139072524405308145;
        ulong g = (((a >> 49 | a << 15) ^ (d >> 33 | d << 31)) + (b ^ (c >> 48 | c << 16)))*8792993707439626365;
        ulong h = (((a >> 17 | a << 47) ^ (b >> 47 | b << 17)) + ((c >> 15 | c << 49) ^ d))*1089642907432013597;
        return (e ^ f ^ (g >> 21 | g << 43) ^ (h >> 44 | h << 20)) * 2550117894111961111 +
            ((e >> 20 | e << 44) ^ (f >> 41 | f << 23) ^ (g >> 42 | g << 22) ^ h) * 8786584852613159497 +
            ((e >> 43 | e << 21) ^ (f >> 22 | f << 42) ^ g ^ (h >> 23 | h << 41)) * 3971056679291618767;
    }
    public double rnddouble(ulong a, ulong b, ulong c, ulong d)
    {
        return (double)(rndlong(a, b, c, d) >> 11) * shift53;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you'd use a seed as the first parameter, and zeros for any parameters you don't need? How did you decide what bitshifts to use? I ask because if I wanted a fifth parameter it'd need to be modified. What do you suggest in this case?

Comment: I tried to make sure that every bit of input potentially influence every bit of output. Multiplication by big number spreads the bits upwards, so with my first bit-shifts I make sure that every bit of input occur in a reasonably low bit of the bit-shifted values, then after the first multiplication the influence of every input bit is spread over most of at least one of the intermediate variables, and then I basically do the same thing again in order to "fill" the remaining gaps.

Comment: The easiest way of getting a longer version is to just daisy chain the 4-input version, like: `rnddouble(rndlong(in1,in2,in3,in4),in5,in6,in7)`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which I'll use until someone convinces me why I shouldn't.

The code below is a usable excerpt of my class. The first `Generate` function can take any number of overloads, depending on your needs. You convert the inputs into byte arrays and pass them to the private Generate method, which does the rest. Note that internally there is a reference to `_seed` which is just a byte array itself, generated from a seed value that you provide via the constructor.

Also, the code takes a dependency on [this MurMurHash3 algorithm](http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/08/murmurhash3-ultra-fast-hash-algorithm.html), which is extremely fast.

I have run a large number of iterations to check distribution and it appears to distribute very evenly, with no obvious human-noticeable clumping around given values. I have it generating a million values in about 720ms on an Intel Core i7, which is plenty fast enough for my purposes. I've also tested it generating 2D white noise on a texture, and the noise looks pretty random.

```
public double Generate(double x, double y, double z, double w)
{
    return Generate(
        _seed,
        BitConverter.GetBytes(x),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(y),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(z),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(w)
    );
}

private double Generate(params byte[][] inputs)
{
    var len = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
        len += inputs[i].Length;
    var buffer = new byte[len];
    var offset = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
    {
        var bytes = inputs[i];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, buffer, offset, bytes.Length);
        offset += bytes.Length;
    }
    return Hash(buffer);
}

private double Hash(byte[] bytes)
{
    var hash = new Murmur3().ComputeHash(bytes);
    var buffer = new byte[8];
    for(var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        buffer[i%8] ^= hash[i];
    var n = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
    if(n < 0) n = -n;
    if(n == long.MaxValue) n--;
    return n / (double)long.MaxValue;
}
```

Comment: A little over a million values per second is actually pretty slow. Also  remember that `-long.MinValue` overflows to `long.MinValue`, if you want to cap the result to positive signed integers you could do `n = n & long.MaxValue`.

Comment: @eBusiness Thanks for the tips, I'll modify mode code accordingly. Given your comment about the speed, what do you suggest I should be doing instead?

Comment: Get rid of Murmur, it may be fast for large blocks of data, but you are still paying a heavy price for initialization. Also, I'm not really sure how you suppose this would work with floats as input, if you want determinism you gotta stay away from floats, unless you really know what you are doing. I guess I could cook up something that doesn't rely on anything expensive.